# How to extract a single column from a set with multiple indices in Pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo

I am using a sparse index (called a Set in Pyomo) `model.x_index` to subset the indices of my Pyomo variable `model.x` before I create it. This is to avoid creating 10+ million instances of my `model.x` variable (that is the total number of original indices).

```
model.x_index = Set(initialize=[(a, i, j, y) for a in model.Biomass for i in model.SourceCounty for j in model.ProdCounty
                                for y in model.Year if model.TD[i, j] < 1000 if model.BP[a, i, y] > 0 if model.FP[a, i, y] < 1000])
model.x = Var(model.x_index, domain=PositiveReals)
```

I now want to extract the fourth column `y` from my `model.x_index` Pyomo Set and store it as a separate Pyomo Set `model.y_index` for indexing another variable I am creating. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more than sure that there will be a more efficient way to do this, but while you get that answer, this may work: Just extract the created index_set from `model.x` and extract just turn them into an actual python `set`

```
y_index = []
for (a,i,j,y) in model.x.index_set():
    y_index.append(y)
model.y_index = pyo.Set(initialize=list(set(y_index)))
model.y = pyo.Var(model.y_index, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
```

Since you got `model-x_index` you can just iterate through it to obtain the same using `for (a,i,j,y) in model.x_index:`

This will give you the basic idea, but you can construct from there.
Also you don't need to mutate `y_index` to set and then re-mutate again into a `list`. I did that because `set(.)` eliminate any repeated value, but if you just pass the original list as argument to `pyo.Set(initialize=y_index)` this will raise a `WARNING` but would work anyway